# Spring security JDK based proxy issue while using @Secured annotation on Controller method

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am doing some RnD to learn Spring Security.While using Method level security I tried following :

**Controller interface**

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @RequestMapping("/admin")
    public interface AdminCtrl {

        @RequestMapping(value = { "/get" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET })
        public @ResponseBody
        String getSomething();
    }
```

**Controller Impl class**

```
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@RequestMapping("/admin")
@Controller
public class AdminCtrlImpl implements AdminCtrl {

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Secured(value = "ROLE_ADMIN")
    public @ResponseBody
    String getSomething() {

        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()
                + "==> Responding with HI";
    }

}
```

**Spring-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" />
    <security:http>
        <security:form-login />
    </security:http>
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="alpha" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"
                    password="password" />
                <security:user name="beta" authorities="ROLE_USER"
                    password="password" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

**app-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.alpha.sample" />
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringSecurity</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springDispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

but when I Access `http://localhost:8080/SpringMethodLevelSecurity/admin/get` .It always login with anonymous user and always shows:

**anonymousUser==> Responding with HI** .

Why it is not showing any authentication mechanism screen eg form-login or http login

__

P.S. Although I know security annotations are mainly belongs to Service Layer .But I want to know the specified case as above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/get" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

under `<security:http>` tag as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

       <security:global-method-security
               secured-annotations="enabled" />
       <security:http>
              <security:form-login />
              <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/get" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
       </security:http>
       <security:authentication-manager>
              <security:authentication-provider>
                     <security:user-service>
                            <security:user name="alpha" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"
                                           password="password" />
                            <security:user name="beta" authorities="ROLE_USER"
                                           password="password" />
                     </security:user-service>
              </security:authentication-provider>
       </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

the key point was that the your system is ready for perform the security checking but you don't have specified the url pattern in which Spring Security must apply the security checking.

In fact the @Secured annotation perform security checking but not directly in the web context but in the "application context" a more correct way in the web context is configure the `<security:http>...</security:http>`
part of the configuration, in other words your configuration doesn't work becouse the filter that you configure acts in base of the `<security:http>...</security:http>`configuration
I hope this can help you

Comment: Well Yes ,I know that I should put <security:intercept-url> in http element but what i want to know than why it is showing anonymous user logged in

Comment: if you see teh doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/authz-arch.html#authz-voting-based you can see tath you have more that one decision voter and probably since in your configuration you don't configure a role for this url pattern spring security fail the first decision voter but not the second becouse you are logged as Anonymus

Comment: It means when an anonymousUser is logged in than it will bypass all security whether method based or url based as here anonymous user do not have _ADMIN_ role (`AuthenticatedVoter` is playing that role for `AccessDecisionManager`)

Comment: the key point was i'm logged, and then spring security use some voters for decide if you have the autority for the resource. in the your first code you don't restrict to the Admin the autority for the resource and for this reason the RoleVoter doesn't block the your request. the my advice is to specify the your security requirements in term of roles in your resource becouse other wise you are logged, in anonymous way but logged in and you popolate the security context than due to yon don't restrict the usage of the web resource the system permit you to browser the resource